# how to Write a routine in the Controller and map it with a URL. Browse the URL and it should display the result

Tags: spring

Methods added in College.java model class

public static List listCollegesForCity(String pCity) {
        return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM College o WHERE o.addressInfoId.city=?1", College.class)
                .setParameter(1, pCity)
                .getResultList();
    }

```
public static List<College> listColleges(String pCity, String pState, String pCountry) {
    return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o from College o WHERE o.addressInfoId.city=?1 AND (?2 IS null or o.addressInfoId.state=?2) AND (?3 IS null OR o.addressInfoId.country=?3)", College.class)
            .setParameter(1, pCity)
            .setParameter(2, pState)
            .setParameter(3, pCountry)
            .getResultList();
}

public static List<College> listColleges(String pCity, String pState, String pCountry, int pFirstResults, int pMaxResults) {
    return entityManager().createQuery(" ", College.class)
            .setParameter(1, pCity)
            .setParameter(2, pState)
            .setParameter(3, pCountry)
            .setFirstResult(pFirstResults)
            .setMaxResults(pMaxResults)
            .getResultList();
}

public static long countColleges(String pCity, String pState, String pCountry) {
    return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(o) from College o WHERE o.addressInfoId.city=?1 AND (?2 IS null or o.addressInfoId.state=?2) AND (?3 IS null OR o.addressInfoId.country=?3)", Long.class)
            .setParameter(1, pCity)
            .setParameter(2, pState)
            .setParameter(3, pCountry)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

}

This is my routine in collegeController.java

//http://localhost:8080/college/colleges/find?city=pune&country=india&state=maharashtra

```
@RequestMapping(value="/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findCollegeForCity(Model uiModel, @RequestParam(value = "city", required = true) String pCity,
       @RequestParam(value = "country", required = false) String pCountry,
       @RequestParam(value = "state", required = false) String pState,
       @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
       @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size) {
    if (page != null || size != null) {
        int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
        final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("colleges", College.listColleges(pCity, pState, pCountry, firstResult, sizeNo));
        float nrOfPages = (float) College.countColleges(pCity, pState, pCountry) / sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
    } else {
        uiModel.addAttribute("colleges", College.listColleges(pCity, pState, pCountry));
    }
    return "colleges/list";
}
```

}

Comment: Please format your code and post.

Comment: Please format your code!!

Comment: I'm just curious... did this work out for you? You didn't accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a `@PathVariable String city` in your method signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{city}",params = { "find=city", "form" }, method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String findCollegeForCity(Model uiModel, @PathVariable String city) { 
   uiModel.addAttribute("colleges", College.listCollegesForCity(city)); 
   return "colleges/find"; 
}
```

Comment: So did this work out for you? Do you have your solution?

Comment: Alexander@- whatever code i pasted above is a working code.

Comment: @DipaliKadam If my answer was the solution or helped you find the right solution, it would be nice if you accepted my answer.